# How to find the biggest subset of an array given some constraints?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, graph

There is an array A[1........N]. How to find the largest subset of the array such that product of any two distinct element of the subset is not a perfect cube. Upper bound for N is 100000.

Example:

```
For A = 1 2 4 8. Answer will be  {1, 2} or {1, 4} or {8, 2} 0r {8, 4}.
```

`1 and 8` cannot come together in the solution.
Similarly `2 and 4`.

My approach.

- check all the subset of the given array and return the subset of maximum length which satisfies the constraint. It will take O(`N*N*2^N`).
- create a graph out of the given array. Two nodes in the graph will be connected if their product is perfect cube. Our main task is to remove the minimum number of nodes such that there are no edges left in the graph (when we remove any node all the edges associated with the node will disappear). Here the main issue is the space (representation of graph). In the worst case size of the graph will be O(`N*N`).

Please help.

Comment: How large can the elements be?

Comment: Lower_Bound = 1 and Upper_Bound = `10^10`

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation

Consider the factorization of each number as follows:

```
A[i] = x^3.y^2.z
```

i.e. we first find the largest cube that divides (and call it x), then the largest square (and call it y), then call whatever is left over z.

The product of `A[i]` with another `A[j]=X^3.Y^2.Z` will be a cube if and only if Y=z and Z=y.

Therefore, if you consider groups of numbers with the same value of y^2.z, these groups form into pairs, where for each pair you cannot take an element from both linked groups.

Clearly the best case is to take all the elements from whichever group is the largest in each pair.

There is one special case, where y^2.z is equal to 1.  In this case, any number in the group is already a perfect cube and cannot be paired with another number from the same group.  Therefore you can add just 1 number from the set of perfect cubes.

### Example

Suppose our array was (expressed as a prime factorization):

```
A[0] = 2^3
A[1] = 3^3
A[2] = 2^2.3.5^3
A[3] = 2^2.3.7^3
A[4] = 2.3^2.13^3
```

We first assign these into groups:

```
Value 1 = Group A (2^3, 3^3)
Value 2^2.3 = Group B (2^2.3.5^3, 2^2.3.7^3)
Value 2.3^2 = Group C (2.3^2.13^3)
```

Group A is paired with itself, while group B is paired with group C.

Therefore we can take one element from group A, and the whole of group B, for a total of 3 elements in the final subset.

Comment: Very nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can formulate it as a largest clique problem.

Create a graph with each number as a vertex and connect two vertices if their product is not a cube.

Now find the largest clique in the graph. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_maximum_cliques_in_arbitrary_graphs